# Mapped list containing components - transfer value to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-redux, create-react-app

In component `BinFormatView` I have mapped array `declarations` and transfer `declaration` to each `BinFormatDeclarationView` component. Simultaneously, transfer State of Redux store to `BinFormatDeclarationView` with other values(like `crude`).

By this, vscode shows the error:
`[js] Property 'declaration' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes <Component <Pick <any, never>, ComponentState >> & Rea ...'.`
Although the code works.

How else should you transfer the value of `declaration` in case mapping?
Is passing values in the component attribute correct if redux is also used?
Can perhaps vscode overdo it?

```
class BinFormatDeclarationViewX extends Component {
    state = {};
    render() {
        const {declaration, crude} = this.props;
        const {symbolSize} = crude;

        return (
            <Fragment>
                {<span className="bin-format_symbol" >{declaration[0]*symbolSize}</span>}
                {<span className="bin-format_symbol bin-format_symbol--relation" >{declaration[1]*symbolSize}</span>}
                {<span className="bin-format_symbol" >{declaration[2]*symbolSize}</span>}
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
const BinFormatDeclarationView = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(BinFormatDeclarationViewX);

class BinFormatView extends Component {
    state = {};
    render() {
        const {crude} = this.props;
        const {declarations} = crude;       
        return (                <ul className="bin-format_list">
                    {declarations.map(declaration => <li className="bin-format_declaration" key={declaration}>
                        <BinFormatDeclarationView declaration={declaration}/>
                    </li>)}
                </ul>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {...state}
}
const ConnectedBinFormatView = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(BinFormatView);
```

**EDIT: When @ts-itgnore**

When add:
`// @ts-ignore`
error hide, but show warrning:
`Comments inside children section of tag should be placed inside braces`
when switch on:
`{// @ts-ignore}`
warrning hide, but show another error:
`Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.`
when switch to:
`{/* @ts-ignore*/}`
last error hide, warrning hide, but back error:
`Property 'declaration' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<any, never>, ComponentState>> & Rea...'.`

How to do it differently?

Comment: How are you getting the error to begin with? It looks like a typescript error. Are you using `// @ts-check` at the top of the script? If so, since your code looks fine, you're safe to ignore the error. The `@ts-check` annotation is only meant for sanity checks, and shouldn't be followed strictly. I'd have written that as an answer but this is only a wild guess

Comment: @kingdaro Yes, I use ts-check. Few options: //@ts-ignore - not work(show else error/warning), {//@ts-ignore} - not work at all, {/*@ts-ignore*/} - not work at all. How do this in different way?

Comment: So you _are_ using the annotation? Then ignore the error like I said. If your code works fine, then the error doesn't mean anything here.

Comment: @kingdaro read the added text from question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to ignore it by using @ts-ignore, I meant to actually not worry about it. Sorry if I was unclear

Comment: Still waiting for answer... :|